# get year in javascript using the last two numbers

Tags: javascript, momentjs

input is `1303` the output must be `March 2013` Is it possible in javascript? i've tried looking for anything especially moment.js but it returns 1980

here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4eG7q/

Comment: Well, what are the rules to convert it?

Comment: hhmm. what rules? what i need is to output it like March 2013.

Comment: -1 If you ever want to convert something, you have to define the rules first .. that's *on you*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var input = "1303";
var date = moment(input, 'YYMM').format("YYYY - MMMM");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eG7q/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 1303 means the 13th year after 2000 and the 03 month in that year, you can dissect it and turn it into a string in plain javascript like this:

```
var input = 1303;
var year = Math.floor(input / 100);
var month = input % 100;

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var output = months[month - 1] + " " + (2000 + year);
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ve4VH/

Answer (score -1):

```
new Date('1303'
.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$2/01/20$1'))
.toString()
.replace(/^.*? (.*?) .*? (.*?) .*?$/, '$1 $2');
```

This will give you Mar 2012, instead of March 2013 but it's cheaper :)